# Way to develop on server in Windows RT

Tags: ftp, ide, windows-rt

Can't find a way to edit files directly on FTP server on my MS Surface (Windows RT 8.1).

I tried to work with «File Manager HD» and «Code writer», and visually it's very good: 3\4 screen is for coding, 1\4 is my FTP directory.
But there is a problem. File doesn't upload to server, when I save it in IDE.

**So, main question — is there ANY way to edit files on my FTP?**
(if there is comfortable way, it will be awesome)

Comment: Have you tried researching?

Comment: I think, that I tried all apps and usual methods, but...
Only mFTP app is working, but it's awful. May be someone had this experience.